# Changing Array causing glitches with splice

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form event which takes entered values and constructs an array out of them using the following:

```
    keywordArray = []    
    var getVal = $('#search').val();
    if(getVal.length > 1){
        keywordArray.push(getVal);
        $('.test').on('click', function(){
            removeTag(this, getVal);
        });
        $('#search').val("");
    }
```

My remove function then looks as follows:

```
    function removeTag(el, getVal){
        var index = keywordArray.indexOf(getVal);
        keywordArray.splice(index, 1);
    }
```

There is no problem when removing a value for the first time as the index is in sync, but once a value is removed the index changes and it seems that JS isn't staying in sync with the updated index, so when I remove another value it glitches with a -1 on splice and will remove all values.

Comment: You're trying to remove values that are no more in the array, right? Add a `if (index >= 0)` test

Comment: How is this "form event" triggered, and how often? Notice you're never removing `click` handlers from those `.test` elements

Comment: i see some issue in you code logic. You are pushing the values in array as `keywordArray.push(getVal);` and removing it on `click` of  `.test`. But how `.test` and newly added tag is associated to each other?

Comment: You seem to be pushing an array into the `keywordArray`. Is this what you want?

Comment: @vijayP is right, you need some kind of association between the click handler and its `getVal`. Perhaps you can use the `data` attribute for that.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is pointed out by @vijayP in the comments. Here is a first possible solution.

When adding a tag, use the `data` attribute to associate the tag with the remove button (`el`):

```
function addTag(el, value) {
    $(el).data('value', value).on('click', removeTag);
}
```

I assume you have a separate remove button for each tag. Then, the click handler function can look like this (with the check for a correct index):

```
function removeTag(){
    var index = keywordArray.indexOf($(this).data('value'));
    if (index > -1) keywordArray.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems: Your `removeTag` function and the way it is called.

First of all, `removeTag()` does not need the element, so remove the `el` parameter if it is really not needed. Second, it should do nothing when the given string does not occur in the array:

```
function removeTag(val){
    var index = keywordArray.indexOf(val);
    if (index >= 0) keywordArray.splice(index, 1);
}
```

The second problem might be related to this part of your code:

```
$('.test').on('click', function(){
    removeTag(this, getVal);
});
```

I suspect that you don't want to register a click handler for all `'.test'` elements because you refer to `this` in the next line but `this` is not used in the `removeTag` function (see above). In case there are several `'.test'` elements, you should make sure that `removeTag()` is only called with the value that corresponds to the clicked `'.test'` element. Currently you call `removeTag()` several times for each click -- once for each `'.test'` element.